# DCount Error MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

This is probably an easy fix. Something my eyes just aren't catching. I keep getting a run time error, 3464 Data type mismatch in criteria expression. The error is in the intX line. I have a command button 'cmdShowLot'. I am trying to check tblLots for a lotID, making sure that the ownerID on tblLots and customerID on the form match. I would be grateful for any help.

```
    Private Sub cmdShowLots_Click()
       Dim intX As Integer
       intX = DCount("fldLotID", "tblLots", "fldOwnerID = '" & Me.fldCustomerID & "'")
       If intX = 0 Then
         MsgBox "This Customer does not own a lot."
       Else
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCutomerLots", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
       End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fldOwnerID is a number, remove the apostrophes form this expression:

```
"fldOwnerID = '" & Me.fldCustomerID & "'"
```

so just

```
"fldOwnerID = " & Me.fldCustomerID
```

Comment: I would also wrap a Nz() (the null to zero function) around the DCount just in case the DCount returns Null (a missing CustomerID on form) which will throw an error.